# How to get the only contacts list names from EWS java API?

Tags: java, office365, ewsjavaapi

I have tried to fetch contacts for Office365. But both contacts list names and contacts getting in the same result. How can i get the contacts list names and contacts separately.

**My Code:**

```
Folder folder = Folder.bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts);    
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
FindItemsResults findResults = service.findItems(folder.getId(), view);
System.out.println(" Resulting Size : "+ findResults.getTotalCount());
for (Item item : findResults.getItems()) {
   try { 
      System.out.println("id:" + item.getId());
      System.out.println("sub==========" + item.getSubject());
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception while processing");
   }
}
```

**Result:**

Resulting Size : 12

> id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwzAAA=
>       sub==========Prem Contact List
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwyAAA=
>       sub==========Ramesh Agile List
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwxAAA=
>       sub==========dshvbisdjkbv 
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwwAAA=
>       sub==========hjdfbvdfbdf
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwvAAA=
>       sub==========jobing
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwuAAA=
>       sub==========pisting
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwtAAA=
>       sub==========non
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwsAAA=
>       sub==========saming
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwrAAA=
>       sub==========Mani Rathnam
>       id:AAMkADkzMDQ5MmUzLTAyMDItNDNjOC04OTBmLWI5ZjhkYzMyYzdhMQBGAAAAAACpdp4753ORRZhtspSlk0QkBwDFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAAAAEOAADFMCvQ3WnzRp46NKMcZvtLAAAVhBwqAAA=
>       sub==========enc